# Neo4J: returning values in common array

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to perform a check and return the values that satisfy a certain predicate in Neo4J

In my hypothetical database, I have a :Trial node label which contains (under the property 'contents') a String Array.[image: Short extract from the graph of the database]

It is critical to note that:

- There are 10,000 :Entry nodes
  _ Each reply has 2 :Trial nodes connected to it

I need to write a query that returns the Z value of all :Entry nodes whose:

- x-value is equal to at least one value in a :Trial node

**AND**

- y-value is equal to at least one value in the other :Trial node

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to choose the appropriate pattern, and then based on it one more, and check it out:

```
MATCH (E:Entry)<--(:Model)<--(:Replies)-->(T1:Trial)
MATCH (E)<--(:Model)<--(:Replies)-->(T2:Trial) 
WHERE T1 <> T2 AND 
      E.X IN T1.content AND
      E.Y IN T2.content
RETURN DISTINCT E.Z AS Z
```